# receiveTimeout property in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I have created on wcf service(self hosted) and using nettcpip binding.There is one more binding called as basicHttpbinding.I have created console application for service.And for consumer also created console application.Here content mode is persession.

Service :

```
namespace InstanceMode_PerCall
{

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
    public class Percall : IPercall
    {
        int number;

        public int Increment()
        {
            number = number + 1;
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

Interface

```
namespace InstanceMode_PerCall
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPercall
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Increment();
    }
}
```

config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

     <bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTCP" receiveTimeout="00:00:03"></binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior" name="InstanceMode_PerCall.Percall">
        <endpoint address="InstanceMode_PerCall" binding="netTcpBinding"  contract="InstanceMode_PerCall.IPercall" name="netTCP"/>
            <endpoint address="InstanceMode_PerCall" binding="basicHttpBinding"  contract="InstanceMode_PerCall.IPercall" />
        <endpoint address="MEX" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Consumer :

```
namespace Consumer_Percall
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer :");

            PercallClient client = new PercallClient("netTCP");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20000;i++)
            {
                int a = client.Increment();
                Console.WriteLine(i +" call :" + a+" Time : "+ DateTime.Now);
                //a = client.Increment();
                //Console.WriteLine("second call :" + a);
                //a = client.Increment();
                //Console.WriteLine("Third call :" + a);
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPercall" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="netTCP" receiveTimeout=""/>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8090/InstanceMode_PerCall"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTCP" contract="PercallConsumerServiceReference.IPercall"
                name="netTCP" />
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/InstanceMode_PerCall"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPercall"
                contract="PercallConsumerServiceReference.IPercall" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPercall" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

For printing it take around 10 sec.But I have mention timeout only 3 sec.Why communication does not stop?where to use receiveTimeout property clientside or service?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding property. Form [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.receivetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets the interval of time that a connection can remain
>   inactive, during which no application messages are received, before it
>   is dropped.

But in you example you constantly ask service to increment value, and inactivity time resets after every request